# Blowfish password_verify doesn't do the job

Tags: php

I'm hashing my passwords with blowfish using Anthony Ferrara's password compactibility library. When I hash 'em they're good, BUT when I try to verify the passwords, doing this:

```
public function Login($username, $postpassword) {

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            if (password_verify($postpassword, $password)) {
                $SESSID = $this->newSession($username);
                $_SESSION['admin_user'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['last_login'] = time();
                header("Location: home.php?SESSID=$SESSID");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Location: index.php?e=false");
        exit();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt->free_result();
}
```

It tells me that me details are wrong... And YES, i did define the `$username` and `$password`:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$postpassword = $_POST['password'];

$users->Login($username, $postpassword);
}
```

Does anybody see the mistake I made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are selecting the user from the database where the username matches the entered username and the password ***hash*** matches the entered *plaintext* password. Of course this will never match anything. You will have to select the username and password from the database only based on the username, then verify the password using `password_verify`.

Comment: So it would be like `SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=?`?